# How to connect Odoo 11 with biometric device ( Not ZK device )

Tags: python-3.6, odoo-11

I have a task that need to connect Odoo 11 with biometric device to solve the problem about attendance. I searched google a lot but nothing can help me and all of document is about connect with "ZK Teco" device. But if another device, is it posible? And what technology in Odoo 11 that i can do to connect? Any suggest for me? Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "not ZK device" ??

Comment: check video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHgdOWkrd-A if this helps. This is has been implemented with the help of http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html.

Answer (score 0):

All biometric devices should be having a database which stores all the relevant data. First find out how does the biometric device store data. If it is in SQL database, you can use SQL commands to retrieve data. One of my client was using an access file and was not ready to move to a SQL database. So I just read the data from the access file itself. So find out how it stores data first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible another devices.
But if you use a ZK device there is already a free module available in the odoo app store to install and work the device with odoo.

Click [this link](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/hr_zk_attendance/) to get the app.(Only works for specific version of devices.)